# The {engine} tag

Tags: discussion, tagging

I suggest that the [engine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/engine) is removed. To me it is too general and vague to serve a purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was going to ask about some details of questions tagged with [engine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/engine) -- What other tags do they feature? Is there a more appropriate tag that [engine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/engine) should be made a synonym of? Then I realized there's only [one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/engine) question so tagged. In that case I suggest you simply remove the existing tag by hand (you have more than enough reputation to do so). Yes, that will bump the respective question to the front page, but you shouldn't worry about one "reanimated" question.

Comment: I am not that savvy with tags so that is why I brought it up here.

Answer (score 3):

If we decide to keep the tag, we should rename it to [engines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/engines).

I think, the tag is useful for comparing the varios TeX engines. Questions which may deserve the tag [engines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/engines):

- [TeX Distribution and Engine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21863/213)
- [The differences between TeX engines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13593/the-differences-between-tex-engines)
- [Differences between LuaTeX, ConTeXt and XeTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36/differences-between-luatex-context-and-xetex)
- [Drawbacks of XeTeX/LuaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3094/drawbacks-of-xetex-luatex)

Possible candidates are question which are about several engines, comparing, such as dealing with advantages and differences.

For example, this question doesn't deserve the [engines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/engines) tag, as it deals only with kerTeX:

- [What is KerTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42234/213)

It's the only one which has the [engine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/engine) tag, we should remove that tag there.

So my suggestion is: let's keep the tag, rename it, and sensibly retag some questions.

Comment: It does indeed fit for your examples. One fear is its generality. We may end up with situations where people tag new questions not only pdflatex but pdflatex + engines and the same for other engines such as xelatex + engines. In these cases the tag engines does not serve purpose, it's merely redundant.

Comment: You and I agree insofar as the [tag:engine] tag should be removed from the one question featuring it right now. ;-)

Comment: @lockstep Done!

Comment: @N.N. That can happen with all general tags. I guess the community sees it and removes a wrong tag. Which is more important: to be able to filter for questions specifically about comparing different TeX engines, or to avoid accidentally mistagging in this regard but giving up that search possibility? Also, then the tag could reappear any time, and neither example tagged questions nor a tag wiki would prevent that.

Comment: @lockstep, N.N. I take this as a personal insult ;-)) (removal of the engine tag)

Comment: @PatrickGundlach Take comfort from your luatex badge. ;-)